# How can I clean Laravel Telescope debug log

Tags: laravel, debugging, laravel-5.7

I just installed [Laravel Telescope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/telescope) which helps me a lot to debug the application. But at this time I want to delete all telescope data-cache and set as like fresh installation. Or is there any way to export the telescope debug log then work with a fresh one?

Thanks for leaving your words.

Comment: The docs seem to indicate the data is stored in `telescope_entries`.

Answer (score 29):

I use in this case `php artisan telescope:clear`. For more information you can look in the artisan help function `php artisan help telescope:clear`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `php artisan telescope:prune` command to clean the Telescope logs.